# Remove a folder from the URL with htaccess only when there are two folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a site that uses wordpress in a /blog/ folder. There's a wordpress plugin that creates a business directory, but the URL is /blog/directory/. I'd like all the /blog/ links to work as normal, but if it's a /blog/directory/ link to remove /blog/ from the URL and just be /directory/

I tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^directory/(.*) blog/$1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /blog/directory/
RewriteRule ^blog/directory/(.*) directory/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Which will work if you directly access the link, so I can put it in custom menus etc. The plugin generates links with /blog/ in it though, so when I click a link generated by the plugin it goes back to /blog/.

I've been working on the .htaccess in the root of the site, and it currently looks like this:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^directory\/(.*) /blog/directory/$1 [L]
```

So is it possible to remove a subfolder from the URL, only when it appears with another subfolder?